# Database connection in Dreamweaver CS4 - grayed out

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express, dreamweaver

I am able to create a database connection when I use ASP (vb) but when I switch my document type to ASP.NET (vb), my add database connection is grayed out. How can I add a SQL database connection while using ASP.NET (vb)??

PS - it is the "+" symbol that is grayed out.. it works fine when I switch the document type to ASP vb.

Thanks,
Ahmet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a deprecated feature...

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402489.html

Thanks,
ahmet